# Approximate join with pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, join, merge

I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2. Both of my dataframes have a column named 'zip_code' and I would like to join df1 and df2 on those columns.

The thing is, in df2, sometimes the strings in the column 'zip_code' is missing one '0' at the beginning. But I would like pandas to detect that they are the 'same' value.

Is there a way to do so without preprocessing my data before ?

Comment: you can pad the strings with leading zeros, or convert both to integers, in which case the leading zeros become meaningless (the latter won't work for zipcodes with dashes, example `01912-001`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think pre-processing is recommended, if not required. Otherwise, when you merge, you will have rows with 2 zip codes, one starting with '0' and the other not.

You can update the offending zip codes in `df2` according to a mask. I assume both `zip_code` series are cast as `str`.

```
# prefixing with 0 causes a zip_code match with df1
mask = ('0' + df2['zip_code']).isin(df1['zip_code'].unique())

# apply the prefix for these cases
df2.loc[mask, 'zip_code'] = '0' + df2.loc[mask, 'zip_code']
```

Then perform your merge as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be lengthy and with the assumption that all the zip codes will have the same length after appending a 0 at the beginning.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],
                 'zip_code':['0234','0345','3456','4567']})

t2 = pd.DataFrame({'id2':[5,6,7,8],
                 'zip_code':['234','0345','3456','4567']})

t2['lens'] = t2.zip_code.apply(len)

t2.loc[:,'zip_code'] = np.where(t2.lens<4,'0'+t2['zip_code'].astype(str),t2['zip_code'])
```

input t1:

```
    id  zip_code
0   1   0234
1   2   0345
2   3   3456
3   4   4567
```

Input t2:

```
    id2 zip_code
0   5   234
1   6   0345
2   7   3456
3   8   4567
```

Output t2:

```
    id2 zip_code    lens
0   5   0234    3
1   6   0345    4
2   7   3456    4
3   8   4567    4
```

you can delete the lens column if you don't need it afterwards. Now you can join the two dataframes t1 and t2 using zip_code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the join function of the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'zip_code':[1000,1001,2000,2002],
        'place':['A','A','B','B']
    }
)

B = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name':['x','y','z'],
        'zip_code':[1001,1000,2000]

})
B['zip_code'] = [x.lstrip('0') for x in B['zip_code']]
B.join(A.set_index('zip_code'), on='zip_code')
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question about pre-fixing missing 0's.

Comment: True. I have missed one step. It's edited and should work now

Answer (score 0):

In this case `Series.str.zfill()` is useful for pre-processing.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'zip5': ['1', '12', '123', '1234', '12345', '123456']})

df.zip5.str.zfill(5)
#0     00001
#1     00012
#2     00123
#3     01234
#4     12345
#5    123456
#Name: zip5, dtype: object
```

This wont affect any zip codes that are longer than or equal to 5 characters, and will fill everything with leading zeroes, in this case up to 5 characters. You can use this to update the zips in your `df2` and then merge as normal.